# KVM Physical NIC access

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I'm new to KVM.  I have a host with 4 NICs. I want to set this up, is it possible?

1. eth0+eth1= bond0 -> internal network
2. build two guests
3. each guest will have network access to 2 subnets ONLY
   eth2 -> subnet2
   eth3 -> subnet3
4. other hosts on subnet2 and subnet3 can access the guests

Should I setup two more bridges? 
but it seems like the other hosts on subnet2 and 3 can't access the guests.

Thanks in advance!!
Will

Comment: I.e. both VMs shall be connected to both eth2 and eth3?

Comment: bridge on every interface you want to have VM comms on, they are really like a virtual switch you plug your VMs into. Make sure you don't use bonding modes 0 and 6 on the bond - those are incompatible with bridging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the physical host, create a bridge `br2` with `eth2` in it, and another bridge `br3` with `eth3` in it.

Now any guest NIC you place in `br2` will have access to whatever's on the other end of `eth2`. Likewise any guest NIC bridged into `br3` will have access to whatever's on the other end of `br3`.

Just like you can have the physical system with `eth2` and `eth3`, you can have a guest with one interface in `br2` and one interface in `br3`. You can also just have a guest with one interface in one bridge only.

You can put a host IP address on the new bridges if you want to. If the host has no need to see what's happening on these other networks, then the host doesn't need to have an IP on these bridges. The Linux bridge is a software implementation of a network switch, so everything works at Layer 2, there's no routing involved which would *require* the host to have an IP address on the bridge.

You can call the bridges whatever you want (`br2`,`kitten1`,`i_like_bacon`, etc) but I'd suggest something that makes it easy to identify either what the bridge is connected to, or what it's for. I try to follow the numbering of the underlying NIC, or an intrinsic name like `office_lan` or `dmz`.

I'd suggest not to have the names swapped around like `eth2` in `br3` and vice versa. One day you're almost sure to put an interface in the wrong bridge then spend a while wondering why it's not working.

Comment: just don't use dashes in bridge names

Comment: Yes. I do want to have both guests access both subnets.  Now. I read that other hosts on the same subnet can't access the guests?  It is a thing for the bridge?  Is it possible to make them "ssh reachable"?

Comment: If that happens then something is set up incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks all. I was reading it wrong and I was on one or two systems didnt' really have the right connection to test the VMs (blame on the network guys).  It all works out fine.